How do I make a swipe animation?
Like here
Now my code looks like this:
 fun CircleWordsSwipe(
       modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
       word: String = "word",
       onGuessed: () -> Unit = { print("+") },
       onNotGuessed: () -> Unit = { print("-") },
    ) {
    var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var dismissedState by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    var lastState by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }



    AnimatedContent(
        targetState = offsetY,
        transitionSpec = {
            scaleIn(
                animationSpec = tween(550, 150),
                initialScale = if (offsetY == 0f) 1f else 01f) togetherWith
                    slideOutVertically(animationSpec = tween(250),
                        targetOffsetY = { offsetY.roundToInt() }) using
                    SizeTransform { initialSize, targetSize ->
                        keyframes {
                            IntSize(targetSize.width, initialSize.height) at 150
                            durationMillis = 100
                        }
                    }
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset {
                IntOffset(
                    x = 0, y = offsetY.roundToInt()
                )
            }.pointerInput(dismissedState) {

                detectVerticalDragGestures(
                    onDragEnd = {
                        offsetY = 0f
                    }
                ) { change, dragAmount ->
                    change.consume()

                    if (offsetY >= 100f && dismissedState) {
                        onNotGuessed()
                        offsetY = 0f
                        lastState = false
                        dismissedState = false
                    } else if (offsetY <= -100f && dismissedState) {
                        onGuessed()
                        offsetY = 0f
                        lastState = true
                        dismissedState = false
                    } else {
                        if (dismissedState)
                            offsetY += dragAmount
                    }
                }
                detectTapGestures(
                    onPress = {  },
                    onLongPress = {  },
                    onTap = {  },
                )


            },


        ) { Content() 
    }
     LaunchedEffect(!dismissedState) {
        offsetY = 0f
        dismissedState = true
    }

}

I don't know exactly how to do this. I tried to do it through AnchoredDraggable, but it didn’t work, so that the element would return back to its initial state. And I decided to do it using AnimatedContent and pointerInput. This option already works, but not perfectly.
I would like to make it so that, for example, I swipe up and it goes up and then appears in the center of the screen. Like in the video

This could be what you're looking for: https://github.com/Tlaster/Swiper

It's a little unfinished
